# Чем создаётся интерфейс (не веб) программы для работы с базой данных?

Tags: база-данных, windows, gui

Хочу сделать телефонный справочник, чтобы работал из exe и позволял добавлять или изменять данные, такое возможно?..

Answer (score 1):

Вариантов масса, если вы имеете ввиду разработку под Windows

- Visual C# WinForms
- Visual C# WPF
- Visual C++
- Visual Basic
- Delphi
- C++ Builder

Если у вас вообще нет опыта в разработке или разработке под Windows я бы посоветовал вам начать изучение с Visual C# (WinForms). Бесплатную редакцию MS Visual Studio можно скачать здесь http://www.microsoft.com/express/Windows/.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ...
А почему здесь, когда вводишь 19 очков награды, цифра сбрасывается на 1 (единицу)?..

Comment: @Freeware Потому что Вы дарите свои очки (они вычитаются из Вашего уважения); у Вас было 1 очко, поэтому цифра сбросилась в 1.

Answer (score 1):

Это возможно, причем практически на любом языке. Кстати очень часто это является учебным заданием для студентов или в школе по информатике.

Подойдет даже Pascal.

Comment: офигенное уточнение делает ответ частично бесполезным) ну тогда даже на delphi)

Answer (score 0):

в таких программах в качестве бд очень удобно использовать xml формат